# How to show total of all postman asserts in Neman Report?

Tags: postman-newman

Newman test reports do not show postman assertions. They only cover one assert for each api.

https://florida23.github.io/aut_api/allure-report/

I have 44 asserts in the apis, but it doesn't count. It only counts one test per api.